# Give an example of a function $u$ and a space $\Omega$ which fails the weak maximum principles

Tags: functions, partial-differential-equations, self-learning, maximum-principle

Let $\Omega \in \Re^2$ be open and bounded. Let $u \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\bar \Omega)$ satisfy

$$-\Delta u = f$$ with $f>0$.

Find an example of $\Omega \in \Re^2$
, $u \in C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\bar \Omega)$,
and $f \in C(\Omega)$ such that

$$\max\limits_{\bar \Omega} u \neq \max\limits_{\delta\Omega} u$$

Ok, so from this I have established that my function $u$ is super-harmonic as $f$ is greater than 0. So I know that it obeys the **minimum** principles.

The issue with this is I don't know how to find an example to show this.

I just need to show that $u$ is non constant and attains it's max in $\Omega$.

I feel like I just need a small amount of guidance in the right direction to solve this.

**Edit:** What I was thinking is to set $u = -x^2 + 2x$ and $\Omega = B_2(0)$ and hence $f=2$. But I am not sure whether this is just a load of rubbish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea (in the edit) works. Here is a slight modification of it.

Superharmonic is kind of like concave (not the same concept but similar), so it's natural to take a simple concave function... upside-down paraboloid comes to mind. And indeed, 
$$
u(x, y) = -x^2-y^2
$$ 
has $-\Delta u = 4$. On the unit disk, the maximum of $u$ is $0$ but the maximum of its boundary values is $-1$.